Using dbt-databricks results in SSLCertVerificationError
I have a project in Databricks. I got the authentication credentials from the portal. They work in DBT Cloud. But I want to do my development locally. So I created my project.
profiles.yml
databricks_dev:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: databricks
      schema: <not-telling-you>
      host: <not-telling-you>.cloud.databricks.com
      http_path: /sql/1.0/warehouses/<not-telling-you>
      token: <not-telling-you>
      threads: 1

But when I do
dbt build

I get:
17:36:15  Running with dbt=1.7.14
using legacy validation callback
17:36:16  Registered adapter: databricks=1.7.14
17:36:16  Found 4 models, 0 sources, 0 exposures, 0 metrics, 548 macros, 0 groups, 0 semantic models
17:36:16  
17:36:16  
17:36:16  Finished running  in 0 hours 0 minutes and 0.14 seconds (0.14s).
17:36:16  Encountered an error:
Runtime Error
  Database Error
    HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<not-telling-you>.cloud.databricks.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sql/1.0/warehouses/<not-telling-you> (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')))

I tried so many ways of adding the cert and disabling SSL verification but had no luck. Can anyone suggest some ideas?
